# The network SDK has not been initialized when connecting to NVR

Tags: python, server, sdk, camera, .net-sdk

I'm encountering an issue when trying to connect to an NVR using a Python script. The script is supposed to initialize the network SDK and then connect to the NVR, but I'm getting an error message saying "The network SDK has not been initialized" when trying to listen for servers. Here's a summary of what's happening:

The dynamic libraries are loaded using a _load_library method.
When attempting to listen for servers, the error occurs.
The script then logs out and finishes.

I'm not sure why the network SDK isn't being initialized properly. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Library Loading: I ensured that the dynamic libraries required for the network SDK were correctly loaded using the _load_library method. I verified the paths to the libraries and confirmed that the loading process was successful.

Initialization: I checked the initialization process of the network SDK to ensure that it followed the correct procedure.